# Discord JS, Await Message, different inputs

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am making a discord bot, choose your own adventure kind of style game. I'm using one command to start it, then Await messages to allow 3 more different responses. I'm using If statements with the response to determine what to do next, however if the message isn't equal to one of the responses then nothing happens.

```
const embed = new discord.RichEmbed()
            .setTitle("__**The Jungle!**__")
            .setColor("#49499c")
            .setDescription("a Pond\nExplore a Tree\nFollow a trail")
            //.attachFiles(["./pictures/Jungle.jpg"])
        const filter = response => {
            return response.author.id === message.author.id;
            }       
        message.channel.send(embed).then(() => {
            message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 30000, errors: ['time'] })
                .then(collected => {
                    if (collected.first()=="Explore a Pond")
                    {
                        Pond.execute(message, args, client);
                    }
                    else if (collected.first()=="Explore a Tree")
                    {
                        Tree.execute(message, args, client);
                    }
                    else if (collected.first()=="Follow a Trail")
                    {
                        Trail.execute(message, args, client);
                    }
                })
                .catch(collected => {
                    message.channel.send('Time up');
                });
        });
```

So I need some sort of catch, and let them try again. Preferably when they input wrong, it would let them put in another input until it's correct. So I imagine it would go up to before the await message again.

Any ideas or help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide more information what you expect to happen when the conditions are not sufficient?

Comment: What about using a default value instead ? Like if none of the choices matches the user's, it gets redirected on a random one

Comment: @Tenclea, its mainly encase they spell it wrong. So id rather try to find to still let them have full control.

Comment: @sebastian-ruehmann ,If the conditions aren't met, I would like it to go back to awaiting a message. So then they can retype the input correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make your code loop itself by calling a function :

```js
const question = function (message) {
    message.channel.send(embed).then(() => { 
    message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 30000, errors: ['time'] }) 
    .then(collected => {
        if (collected.first()=="Explore a Pond") { Pond.execute(message, args, client); } 
        else if (collected.first()=="Explore a Tree") { Tree.execute(message, args, client); } 
        else if (collected.first()=="Follow a Trail") { Trail.execute(message, args, client); } 
        else { message.channel.send("Could not find this answer"); return question(message); }
    })
     .catch(collected => { message.channel.send('Time up'); }); });
}
```

Please tell if me you encounter any kind of problems with this :)